# On click of a button display different partial views in a particular div on condition

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2008-r2

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="bindpartialviews">
    @Html.Partial("_ReportHD")
</div>
```

Is it possible to bind different partial views based on condition onclick of a button in the above div?

My ajax method are as below:

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: yourApp.Urls.GetAllReports,
        data: { SearchValue: searchval },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#bindpartialviews").html(result);                
        }
    });
```

I Have two different partial views(It may increase in no.). 
1) _ReportHD.cshtml
2) _ReportSD.cshtml

In my form I have a dropdown. Based on the selected value, it will load different partial view on click of a single button.

I have used ASP.Net MVC 4,JQuery. Any help is welcome.

Comment: On button click you are calling some method by ajax right? If yes then show as your controller method.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: #Stephen Muecke - on single click how to show different partial view, I am not getting the way. Any sample may workout for me.

Comment: You have not shown any relevant code for your view (the form, the dropdownlist or the button) or the controller method that you want to call (and to notify a user its `@username`, not `#username`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a simple method in Controller. Then based on the condition you have to return a partial view.

**Controller Method**

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Choose View based on selected dropdown value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputParam">Parameter.</param>
        /// <returns>Partial view.</returns>
        public PartialViewResult ChooseView(string inputParam)
        {
            //Here add your condition.
            if(inputParam=="A")
            {
                return PartialView("_ReportHD");
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("_ReportSD");
            }
        }
```

**Then call the AJAX function on button click.  So then you can easily bind that in any div.**

Note: You have to pass the selected dropdown value.

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        datatype:"text",
        url: "/ControllerName/ChooseView?inputParam="+searchval,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#bindpartialviews").html(result);                
        }
    });
```